# multiple (p5.js) sketch.js files not working, only last one is working

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I am working on a project, using p5.js library. In my index.html, I have 3 different sketch.js files (sketch.js, wiki.js, weather.js), only last one is working, if I add 3 or two, but all are working separately.
Help Me Please.

```
<head>
all libraries here.....after them
<script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="wiki.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="weather.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] showing what's in the JavaScript files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. In your case a simple example showing a basic example of what's in your JavaScript files would really help.

Without a MCVE this is just a guess, but it sounds like you're looking for **instance mode** in P5.js. I'm guessing your sketches all look like this:

```
function setup(){
  //setup code here
}

function draw(){
  //drawing code here
}
```

So every time you load a new file, you're overwriting the previous `setup()` and `draw()` functions. Instead, what you need to do is use instance mode, so your sketches look like this:

```
var sOne = function( sketch ) {

  sketch.setup = function() {
    //setup code
  };

  sketch.draw = function() {
    //drawing code
  };
};

var sketchOne = new p5(sOne);
```

You'd use different variable names in each file, but the idea is the same. Now your sketches are each self-contained.

More info [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode).